# VARCHAR2 datatype in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, varchar2

I am very new to oracle and today I found about the data type **VARCHAR2**, and I wanted to learn more about it and google the datatype where I met the problem.

I have gone through few articles about the datatype, and I found out some direct opposite descriptions for **VARCHAR2**.

**DESCRIPTION 1:**

- When you create a table with a VARCHAR2 column, you specify a maximum
  column length (in bytes, not characters) between 1 and 2000 for the
  VARCHAR2 column([article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch6.htm#varchar2))

**DESCRIPTION 2:**

- you can store up to 4000 characters in a VARCHAR2 column. ([article](http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-varchar2/))

As you can see it is bit confusing. Is **VARCHAR2** is to specify the **maximum column length** or **maximum characters length**? Somebody please explain me which one is the correct one?

Comment: Your first link is to Oracle version 7. That was current last century...

Comment: @Mat I am really sorry. I didn't know about oracle versions. I am really new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your Oracle version, but both articles are mostly incorrect.

When you DECLARE the column, you can either declare the stated length EXPLICITLY as either bytes or characters, or IMPLICITLY using your session's default.

Also, the maximum length is 4000 bytes, NOT characters. Even if you declare VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), the column cannot store more than 4000 BYTES. It will store 4000 characters if they are all single-byte, otherwise it will store fewer than 4000 characters.

Comment: This makes sense. You mentioned that "It depends on oracle version".If possible can you elaborate

Comment: @Ramesh - I just did, under the other Answer.

Comment: I have gone through it. Thank you for your valuable time sir

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that in newest release (12c) you can optionally extend the limit to 32767 bytes.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - it was noted already, I said *It depends on your Oracle version*!

Answer (score 1):

DESCRIPTION 2:

- you can store up to 4000 characters in a VARCHAR2 column.

This is correct

The VARCHAR2 datatype stores variable-length character strings. When you **create a table with a VARCHAR2 column**, you specify a **maximum string length** (in bytes or characters) **between 1 and 4000 bytes** for the VARCHAR2 column.

Comment: But the description 1 is from the oracle documentation

Comment: @Ramesh - OK, your comment above made me follow the first link. It is to Oracle 7. That probably means the limit (30 years ago or whenever that was) was indeed 2000 bytes - and perhaps you couldn't declare the length in characters. Not sure when both of these things changed, but it's at least since Oracle 10.2. I use Oracle 12.2, and that is not even the most current version. And in Oracle there are huge changes from one version to the next.

Answer (score 0):

=> varchar2 datatype is same as varchar datatype.
=> its datatype with variable lengh.
    Ex. "name varchar2(20)" and pass the value of name is "Ram" so, LENGTH(name) is 3 NOT 20.
=> its internal datatype managed by oracle server only.
=> even if, you declare varchar oracle implicitely converts to into varchar2